# Remove "Ads by Games Crystal" malware from Chrome on a Mac

Tags: security, google-chrome

A user on one of our computers infected her user with some kind of adware malware that results in pop-back ads by "GamesCrystal", an ad that appears on random sites with a tag "Ads by Games Crystal" in the bottom, and multiple calls to various unfamiliar servers.

I tried various things to get this removed. There was nothing obvious in Chrome that I could tie to Games Crystal. [Malwarebytes for Mac](https://www.malwarebytes.com/antimalware/mac/) didn't detect anything. Spotlight doesn't show any files with names like "Games Crystal" or any of the permutations of that I tried. There weren't any unfamiliar apps to delete in `/Applications` or `~/Applications`.

How do you get rid of this malware?

Comment: Malwarebytes for Mac didn't detect it because this software is embedded in another downloaded software as a free bonus, rather poison. You might discover it as an extension within your web browser.

Comment: That would make sense, as when we reset Chrome that cleared it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I was hoping to find a more surgical solution, I ultimately settled on simply resetting Chrome, by following the instructions [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214):

1. On your computer, open Chrome.
2. At the top right, click More > **Settings**.
3. At the bottom, click **Show advanced settings**.
4. Under the section "Reset settings,” click **Reset settings**.
5. In the box that appears, click **Reset**. ​

So far, no additional Games Crystal ads have displayed, so hopefully this took care of it.

Comment: I'm at more than a month with no additional ads, so I think this did it.

Answer (score 0):

These ads are injected by third party ad-serving systems that are embedded in the web pages you visit. You can't remove them from your system because there's nothing on your system to remove that's related to them.

Block ad services in your browser with something like [uBlock](https://www.ublock.org/) and they'll never appear.

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct.  For example, we were seeing them on Khanacademy on her user and on no one else's user, and once we reset Chrome we're not seeing them there any more.